# Elasticsearch Snapshot Fails With RepositoryMissingException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

Three node ElasticSearch cluster on AWS. Bigdesk and Head both show a healthy cluster. All three nodes are running ES 1.3, and the latest Amazon Linux updates. When I fire off a snapshot request like:

```
http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/taxanalyst/201409031540-snapshot?wait_for_completion=true
```

the server churns away for several minutes before responding with the following:

```
{
  "snapshot": {
    "snapshot": "201409031521-snapshot",
    "indices": [
      "docs",
      "pdflog"
    ],
    "state": "PARTIAL",
    "start_time": "2014-09-03T19:21:36.034Z",
    "start_time_in_millis": 1409772096034,
    "end_time": "2014-09-03T19:28:48.685Z",
    "end_time_in_millis": 1409772528685,
    "duration_in_millis": 432651,
    "failures": [
      {
        "node_id": "ikauhFYEQ02Mca8fd1E4jA",
        "index": "pdflog",
        "reason": "RepositoryMissingException[[faxmanalips] missing]",
        "shard_id": 0,
        "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
      }
    ],
    "shards": {
      "total": 10,
      "failed": 1,
      "successful": 9
    }
  }
}
```

These are three nodes on three different virtual EC2 machines, but they're able to communicate via 9300/9200 without any problems. Indexing and searching works as expected. There doesn't appear to be anything in the elasticsearch log files that speaks to the server error.

Does anyone know what's going on here, or at least where a good place to start would be?

**UPDATE**: Turns out that each of the nodes in the cluster need to have snapshot directories that match the directory specified when you register the snapshot with the elasticsearch cluster.

I guess the next question is: when you want to tgz up the snapshot directory so you can archive it, or provision a backup cluster, is it sufficient to just tgz the snapshot directory on the Master node? Or do you have to somehow consolidate the snapshot directories of all the nodes. (That can't be right, can it?)

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch supports shared file system repository uses the shared file system to store snapshots.
             In order to register the shared file system repository it is necessary to mount the same shared filesystem to the same location on all master and data nodes.

All you need to know Put in elasticsearch.yml of all 3 nodes same repository_name.
             for eg:-
                 path.repo:[/my_repository]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this aws plugin for elasticsearch (I guess you already installed it to configure your cluster) : https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws#s3-repository

It will allow you to create a repository mapped to a S3 bucket.
To use (create/restore/whatever) a snapshot, you need to create a repository first. Then when you will do some actions on a snapshot, Elasticsearch will directly manage it on your S3 bucket.

Comment: I've looked at that as well, but chatter on "The Internet" indicates that the S3 snapshot is, if not deprecated, then discouraged. (http://bit.ly/1wEHhuL) When asked what to use instead, the answer I've heard is "use EBS". So I guess that leaves us with n nodes with n attached EBS devices holding n snapshots of the state of each node in the cluster. I guess When the cluster goes down you spin up n new nodes and attach the matching EBS to each. Sounds like a fun maintenance exercise. Having said that I'm using the S3 snapshot anyway.  :)

Comment: @IanC I think you're confusing "snapshots" with the old elasticsearch S3 "gateway", which was removed in ES 1.2. Backing up and restoring your elasticsearch data from S3 is supported. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elasticsearch/aNUw4nFT6JE/JKDkffZT60sJ